# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_thread-mt

Tags: c++, linux, boost

I am trying to link a project with the following command:

```
g++  build/test.o -o bin/test -pthread -L lib  -L /home/alexander/opt/lib -lboost_thread-mt
```

which results in the following errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_thread-mt
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

However, the `boost` libraries are installed in the directory `/home/alexander/opt/lib`. Why does the linker do not find the boost libraries? I also tried to link with `-I` instead if `-L` with the same outcome...

Content of `/home/alexander/opt/lib` is `/home/alexander/opt/lib/boost_1_57_0`.

Comment: The directory you point to with `-L` has to contain `libboost_thread-mt.so`. If this is not the case, change it (for example to `/home/alexander/opt/lib/boost_1_57_0`.

Comment: And the `-I` has nothing to do with this at all, it's for the include directories (for your preprocessor to lookup files that you `#include`).

Comment: Ok great, seems that I do not have boost installed at all. Anyone knows how to install boost? I guess it is an incredible complicated and insane procedure... but tell me anyway

Comment: What operating system/distribution are you running? Most have packages for boost.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention: Linux/Ubuntu

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev`

Comment: How do you know that? Just googled or is there a pattern when you want to install something with `apt-get`? Its NEVER the name of the software you want to install, it always has e.g. an `all` added or a `dev` or some number. Why not just `apt-get install <name>`?

Comment: But if you install Boost with apt-get, it will be quite outdated. If you already have the sources of 1.57, just build them! From within boost root dir invoke `./b2 release stage` - and the libs will be in `boost_1_57_0/stage/lib`

Comment: I followed the instructions given here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22470265/how-to-install-boost-on-gnu-linux. And so far, I am VERY confused. No error yet! I guess they will still come...

Comment: The only potential pitfall here is mixing different Boost version (eg. if you use headers from older version, but link libs from the newer one).

Comment: Compilation of boost seem to have gone through without problems (surprisingly...), and including `/usr/local/lib` seems to let the linker find the correct library. So thank you all for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

change libboost_thread-mt to libboost_thread, first find the address of libboost_thread.so and libboost_thread.a then make softlinks to these files in the same address, 
so it should be:

```
ln -s /...libboostSourceFiles.../libboost_thread.so /..RequestTOmtFiles.../libboost_thread-mt.so
```

it works for other libboost -mt files too, like serialization , iostreams, programoptions